# How do i select Button and also set focus on TextBox at a time in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am creating a windows form using C#. My problem is that I want to set focus on the Text Box control and also select the log in button at the same time.

If I enter something in the Text Box, it accepts that string.
But when I press "Enter" key, I want to fire the log in button click event directly.

Comment: Change the form's AcceptButton property, select the button.  Now it *looks* like the default button *and* it is automatically clicked when you press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Set a KeyUp listener on the TextBox and listen for the Enter key. If they press enter then submit the form. You don't need to specifically select the login button. Focus on the text box.